Getting #N/A when trying to MATCH a data column in a table to another column (computed) in same table
I have a Table1 with columns

[@First]
[@Last]
[@Age]
[@Partner]
[@Partner_Age]
[@People] computed as =MID([@First],1,1)&"."&[@Last]

I am trying figure out a formula for the Partners age. Something like:
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(...row of partner..., ...@AGE column...))
First,Last,Age,Partner,Partner_Age,People
A,P,30,C.R
B,Q,35,D.S
C,R,32,A.P
D,S,33,B.Q

My first step of the formula is failing to get the row of the partner,
=MATCH([@Partner],[@People]) is always #N/A

[People]... no @.

You probably also want exact matching. Also =LEFT([@FIRST]) == =MID([@First],1,1)

@JvdV I never realised that LEFT without the [num chars] parameter assumed it was 1 (even though it's got the square brackets).  Has it been like that since Excel 97?  Learn something new every day. :)

If you have Excel 365 you can use the FILTER- formula:
=FILTER([Age],[People] = [@Partner])

But you will receive an error in case of duplicates ...

